# How can I take tuple as input using raw_input in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to take input. But it's not the correct syntax.

```
a, b, c = (int(x) for x in raw_input().strip(' '))
```

My idea is to take multiple values from single line which has integers separated by space. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

You were very close.  It's `split` not `strip`:

```
a, b, c = (int(x) for x in raw_input().split())
```

This will take exactly 3 integers, no more no less.  If you want to take an arbitrary amount into a tuple, try this instead:

```
tup = tuple(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and suggestion.

Comment: Do you even need the `(int(x) for x in ..` - wouldn't `a, b, c = *raw_input().split()` be sufficient? (No python on my chromebook so I can't test it out.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want the split function, not the strip function. That will return an array that you can iterate over. The strip function will just remove initial and trailing characters (in your case spaces).

That will throw an exception if the user doesn't enter data in the correct format though.